# Confusion between jQuery Deferrable, jsDeferred, and just deffering in general

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I downloaded a library called `jsdeferred` to try and help me with some code-flow problems, but I am a little lost, as its examples and ...*'documentation'* is a little unclear on some things. But as I kept reading and digging, and of course googling everything under the sun, I also found out jQuery has its own `Deferred()` system. I am linking both here, for proper context.

### [Link to jsDeferred Library](http://cho45.stfuawsc.com/jsdeferred/)

### [Link to jQuery.Deferred()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/)

## The Problem

I need to find a way to tell the page to **"hold on until the last thing is done"**.

This is what **thought** *`jsdeffered`* did. So **part of my question** is asking **which should I use? jsDeferred or jQuery.Deferred();** and then **how to use it** as I've outlined below.

## The Situation

My scenario is this, in a nutshell, I need to perform the following behavior.

- page loads, a `view model` is defined

This is using `kendo ui mvvm` to declare my view model, so it is a `kendo.data.ObservableObject`

- an `$.ajax` call is made to the database to get some default model data

This is where I am getting the most trouble. I need everything to "hold on" until this `$.ajax` is done. But I don't want to wrap everything in the `$.ajax().done(r)` if I can help it. That looks/feels very sloppy to me and is kind of confusing at times.

- other widgets on the page are rendered, they have respective database queries done through `kendo ui Remote DataSource`.

These are actually working as intended.

- `jQuery Validate` is wired to the view, with defaults having been set already.

This is also working as intended.

- `kendo.bind('body', viewModel);` is called to perform model binding.

Now this is where I am running into trouble, going back to `step 2` where I was making the `$.ajax` call. What keeps happening is that `kendo.bind` is fired before the `$.ajax` completes. I can put it in the `$.ajax({}).done();` function, and for **this exact one specific page** that does work, but there will be many other situations where that isn't suitable.

## What I have tried

First, I'll be clear that the `jsdeferred` documentation is very unclear to me, as running its samples verbatim doesn't actually work. I am continuously told that `next is not defined` and the like. I eventually figured out that you have to have an implicit `Deferred.` before you call `next` the first time.

So here is what I **thought** would happen...

```
var viewModel = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
   // various view model properties defined
});

Deferred.define();

next(function() { // let's call this STEP 1
   $.ajax({
      // data for ajax to controller
   }).done(function(result) {
      // perform operations with result
   });
}).
next(function() { // let's call this STEP 2
   $('#dropdownlist_target').kendoDropDownList({
      // parameters, remote data source for drop down list, etc.
   }).data("kendoDropDownList");
}).
next(function() { // let's call this STEP 3
   $('form').validate({
      // any extra form validation stuff
   });
}). 
next(function(){ // let's call this STEP 4
   kendo.bind('body', viewModel);
});
```

I believed that these would each run one, right after the other, when the previous one is finished. But that is **not** what is happening. `STEP 1` is still in the process of fetching while `STEP 2, 3` and `4` are running.

This doesn't seem to be any different than the way the code was running without the `jsdeferred` library. So I am very confused and would absolutely love some help here. I need `STEP 1` to be completely finished before `STEP 2` fires, basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `next()` expects you to *return* the *thing* you want it to wait for. In step one, you're not returning anything. `jsdeferred` is therefore assuming you were performing a synchronous operation (that has already finished), and so it continues with step 2.

Instead, return the `jQuery.Deferred()` returned from the `$.ajax()` call. jsdeferred will then wait for that to complete *before* it executes step 2.

---

Regardless of this, I'd dump `jsdeferred`. As you've realised, jQuery has a fully fledged Deferred implementation. I'm not sure what jsdeferred brings to the party.

**Using `$.ajax().done(r)` is not sloppy. Asynchronous behaviour is the *core* of event driven languages, and JavaScript is one. Embrace it, or you'll go bald *very* early in life trying to avoid it**.

If you revert to jQuery's Deferred implementation, you might like [`then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/), to give you the semantics of `next()`;

```
$.ajax({
   // data for ajax to controller
}).done(function(result) {
   // perform operations with result
}).then(function () {
    $('#dropdownlist_target').kendoDropDownList({
       // parameters, remote data source for drop down list, etc.
    }).data("kendoDropDownList");

    $('form').validate({
       // any extra form validation stuff
    });

    kendo.bind('body', viewModel);
}).then(function () {
    // Note you can chain then()'s as well.
});
```

Comment: When I say `"sloppy"` I don't mean _bad code_. I mean that I, personally, have a lot of trouble understanding when things are firing off - I'm not very well versed in all the async stuff yet, so it ends up being sloppy __to me__ because I'm still learning how to reign it in properly.

Comment: And yes, I do need to learn to do it more. I completely agree - it is just a difficult process sometimes.

Comment: Hey @Matt, this was perfect. You understood exactly what I was trying to accomplish and the presentation is easy to read. I thought `done` was exclusive to `$.ajax`, and that is where I was getting lost on that. This will make a lot of code easier to write!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it possible to do such a chain as this __without__ an `$.ajax` call? Like what sort of other object could this be done with?

Comment: @Ciel: Ah, sorry... I misinterpreted what you meant :). The jqXHR object (which is what jQuery's ajax() method returns) exposes the same methods that a jQuery.Deferred's promise() will. jQuery has documentation for all of these methods and types which might help it sink in, although I'll admit jQuery's documentation for Deferreds as a whole is crap. However, the good news is that the concept of promise's and deferreds is pretty standardised, so any documentation you can find on the subject may help the idea's sink in. Sorry I can't provide any links, I'm on my phone, but I hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah, I tried to read their documentation on `deferred` and `promise` and I think blood began to shoot out my ears.

Comment: I just wanted to come back to this and let you know that this is completely awesome. So much of my code has been able to be re-worked to run so, so, so much smoother now and exactly as I wanted it to without having to do so much stupid sideline works.

Comment: To comment on something you said, you said `"I would suggest you ditch deferredjs"`, I presume that is because you feel it doesn't replace the built in jQuery `$.Deferred`. I have spent a day researching it pretty extensively and while I think I agree with you on the level of __functionality__, I think on the level of __entry level readability__, `deferredjs` is still a really good library. I am starting to see that it doesn't accomplish anything I can't do with `$.Deferred`, but it does it with what I've heard at times called `syntax sugar` - or rather, it is easier to type.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `then` method on your `$.ajax()` result in the same way you're using jsDeferred's `next` helper. Generally speaking, `then` is a more flexible method than `done`. And as Matt noted in his answer, it's a common mistake in promise based programming to forget to `return` a new promise within the handler, causing it to resolve prematurely with `undefined` instead of waiting on a the new promise.

```
$.ajax({  // let's call this STEP 1
   // data for ajax to controller
}).
then(function(result) {
   // perform operations with result
}).
then(function() { // let's call this STEP 2
   $('#dropdownlist_target').kendoDropDownList({
      // parameters, remote data source for drop down list, etc.
   }).data("kendoDropDownList");
}).
then(function() { // let's call this STEP 3
   $('form').validate({
      // any extra form validation stuff
   });
}). 
done(function(){ // let's call this STEP 4
   kendo.bind('body', viewModel);
});
```

Note that in my refactoring, all of those `then`s will execute immediately in a row, unless a new promise is returned. So you may as well combine them.

[`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) takes a function that either returns a value or a promise, and it returns a new promise. If its function returned a value, the new promise is immediately resolved with that value. If its function returned a promise, then that promise is passed through as the new promise. Note that jQuery's `then` only works this way as of jQuery versions >=1.8.

Comment: Hey, this was also useful in conjunction with the accepted answer. Thank you so much. If I may ask, is it possible to do this sort of chaining with any other kind of object than just an `$.ajax` call?

Comment: Absolutely! The jqXHR object returned by `ajax` responds to the same methods as a jQuery promise. You can make those yourself using `$.Deferred`.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to read up on `$.Deferred` but man, it makes my head spin. I am starting to see why `jsdeferred` was written. I think that `jsdeferred` was made before `$.Deferred` became a bigger part of jQuery (I cannot prove that, though).

Comment: I highly recommend reading https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970 to really internalize how promises work. Then, you really just need to understand the two primary ways of creating a promise. There's the functional way, in which you are passed resolve and reject callbacks, as illustrated here (https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#whenpromise). Then there's the OOP way, as typified by `$.Deferred` and here (https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#whendefer), in which you use the methods of a deferred object with methods to resolve and reject the promise.

Comment: @Ciel ^ (to get your attention)

Comment: Yeah! All three of those links are really good. I'm reading up on them thoroughly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's difficult to really explain, but I both 'get it', and I do not get it at the same time. I'm actually not a bad programmer but async stuff always trips me up because of the way examples are done. They're always such trimmed, slim, un-lifelike examples - if that makes any modicum of sense. All of this stupid `foo` and `bar` stuff  makes my head spin. These links you provided though show true, actual use as they might be seen in the 'wild', so to speak. That helps it to be absorbed a lot easier.